# IIS not calling PHP for <?= x ?>

Tags: php, iis-7

```
<?= x ?>
```

That's short for `<?php echo x ?>` and works fine on my local Apache with PHP, but the ISS 7 PHP on the server doesn't process it.

Is there a setting i missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a setting in php.ini called '[short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)' that should be set to `on` if you are using PHP prior to version 5.4.0

From the manual:

> Note:
> This directive also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to `<?` echo. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.